# Adding StartCom Certificates in Java (Netbeans)

Tags: java, ssl, netbeans

I am making an Java client application that needs to access some data from website using https and signed by **StartCom**.

First, I tried to use HttpsURLConnection to access https://blabla.com/blabla.file, but I got `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.` error.

I guess the reason is that StartCom is not added in Java trust certs.

Then, I added two StartCom certificate files (ca.crt and startcom.sub.class1.server.ca.crt) in Java `cacerts` and I can see them with `keytools`, but I still get the same error as before.

So, **is it possible to use StartCom signed websites in java application without adding it to Java cacerts**, and

**why can not I use StartCom signed websites even if I added their certificates to my cacerts file**, what did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance!

*Edit 1: If I try to access https://google.com (for example) from my application there are no errors.*

*Edit 2: Certificates where added by this command `keytool -keystore cacerts -importcert -alias startcom.ca -file ca.crt`.*

Comment: Better to use visual tools like http://portecle.sourceforge.net/.